# div tag wrap around object besides float

Tags: css, html, tags, stylesheet

i've been searching and i know that float:left or float whatever does that, but what if I don't want to use float? Is there another way to make a div tag wrap around its contents? if i do

`border: thin solid black;`

it will show that by default the div tag is 100%.

Thank you

Edit: I have a div tag wrapped around a form

```
<div class='subHolder'>
<form action="" method="get">
<input type='text' class='subscribe' name='subscription'/>
<a class='buttonSubscribe orange'>Subscribe</a>
</form>
</div>
```

This is the style sheet

```
div.subHolder {
padding:30px;
margin:0 auto;
border:thin solid black;
display:inline-block;
```

}

How do I set it so it will float in the middle of the page?

Thank you

Comment: your question is unclear - Please try giving an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you want

```
display:inline;
```

check out w3schools http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_display.asp`

Comment: nice! thank you :) inline-block worked for me instead of just inline. But weird, `margin: 0 auto;` doesnt work. It won't allow my div table to go into the middle.

Comment: try adding text-align:center to the div containing your inline-block div

Comment: the thing is that I'm wrapping around form. will that have problems?

Comment: can you edit your question and add some of your code so I can get a better idea?